# Android Accessibility change focus listener

Tags: android, android-viewpager, accessibility

I want to set a onFocusChangeListener when accessibility is changing focus in a view pager.

So basically right now through accessibility I can access first 2 pages of the view pager not the third one. I have also tried setting the offScreenPageLimit of the view pager to 6 on my OnCreate but it still doesn't work.

What I have tried so far :

1. mPager.setOnGenericMotionListener
2. mPager.setOnFocusChangeListener

   ```
   3. mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
           Log.d(TAG,"on page scrolled");
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           Log.d(TAG,"on page selected");
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
           Log.d(TAG,"on page scroll state");
       }
   });
   ```

Please help.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can extend ViewPager and override dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent (please call super too)

Once you do that and add the conditions as mentioned below you can realize your dreams about learning accessibility hover enter/exit

```
dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_EXIT) {
           //...
        } else if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER) {
           //...
        }
}
```

TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED is more elegant when compared to hover as it cover accessibility focus scenarios without human hover/touch too

Refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)

Comment: How do you distinguish between **ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED** and **TYPE_VIEW_HOVER**?  They're both firing.

Comment: I had seen a visually impaired person changing accessibility focus box (from one ui element to another) by swiping repeatedly on just one area of the screen. (read as focusing on element without touching/hovering over the view),